# Android: should I launch a new activity or show a dialog?

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

Let's say I want my app to display a file browser.  Are there any significant advantages or disadvantages to having this file browser extend Dialog instead of extending Activity?  I was unable to to find anything useful in the documentation; any input?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest, it's all about user experience. So if they are just going to be selecting a file and that's it, then I would recommend using a Dialog. If you want it to do a lot more than just selecting a file and then disappearing, then definitely open it up in a new Activity.

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is in user experience.  I assume you're referring to the activty being fullscreen and the dialog being not?  But, both dialog and activity can be configured to be fullscreen or not, so this isn't an advantage or disadvantage for either?

Comment: Well, you could get full benefits from either, but they each have their uses. The whole purpose of a Dialog is to have a small window, usually for prompting the user for information. And an Activity is used as a main viewing page. A Dialog can't exist the same way an Activity can - Dialogs have to be spawned from an Activity (Context).

Comment: So you would say that in this scenario, there is significant advantage or disadvantage to either?

Comment: I would say it's more advantageous to use a Dialog, simply because it doesn't have as much over-head as starting a whole new Activity. But if you plan on using it for more than just prompting the user for information, then I'd say, start a new Activity.

Comment: You can quickly test how your activity would look like Dialog by applying  _android:theme_ attribute on you _<activity/>_: `<activity android:name=".YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">`